# Who is Tarquin?

Tags: mass-effect-3

After curing the Genophage on Tuchanka, I was talking to James and he said "Too bad about Tarquin, I was just starting to like him."  Is this a misinterpretation of

> Mordin's

name or someone who I have forgotten entirely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tarquin is Lieutenant Tarquin Victus. The Primarchs son.

You rescue him during the mission Tuchanka: Turian Platoon, and afterwards, accompany him on the mission Tuchanka: Bomb.

> Sadly, he dies at the end of that last one.

Comment: *faceplams* Of course! Do you remember when you learn his first name? I only remembered him as "Lieutenant Victus", for whatever reason.

Comment: When you first land on the planet to rescue him, you'll hear his full name in some squad dialog.